# how can I fix the error message: "the file is readonly" in cplex?

Tags: cplex

when I run my configurations, it says that I have an error:" IBM ILOG Concert: Error: The file is readonly." What does that mean and how can I fix that?
Thank you

Comment: Help us to help you by giving us some more basic info - what OS are you using, what version of CPLEX, what language are you using, what does your code look like, what is in your configurations, which files are your code trying to open, what have you done so far to investigate?

Answer (score 1):

"Error: The file is readonly." means the process is trying to write to a file, but the process only has permissions to read the file.

The issue is likely due to installing/setting up as root, then running as non-root, but it's difficult to say without knowing more details like what file is being complained about, what permissions it has, and how you set up this process

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, this error appears if you try to write the output to an external file and run the model while the file is still open. Then you need to save and close that file and try to run the model.